# Dynamic import does not find file when .js extension

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this small TS app.

Where i have an file called `en.js` which looks like:

```
export default {
   name: "test"
}
```

When i try to import it, it does not work:

```
await import("./en.js")
```

It says `code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'`

But if i rewrite it to an `.json` it works:

```
//en.json
{
   "name": "test"
}
```

Then the import works just fine:

```
await import("./en.json");
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be declared as a const in order to be exported as a module.
Please try the following

```
export default const Test = {
   name: "test"
}
```

Comment: This syntax is wrong by just looking at it